# Create a Compute Engine with the internet access by using Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-networking

Running the following terraform gcp project i can see the machines do communicate with each other but no internet, machines looks to resolve the domains but not able to ping them. I am adding internal static ip  since i need to be static in order for the instances to communicate with each other.

Anything i am missing?
Thank you in advance

```
provider "google" {
  project     = "terraform-368808"
  region      = "us-west1"
}

resource "google_compute_network" "default" {
  name = "manager-network"
  auto_create_subnetworks = false
  mtu                     = 1460
}

resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "default" {
  name          = "manager-subnet"
  ip_cidr_range = "10.10.10.0/24"
  region        = "us-west1"
  network       = google_compute_network.default.id

}


resource "google_compute_address" "manager_ip_one" {
  name         = "manager-ip-one"
  subnetwork   = google_compute_subnetwork.default.id
  address_type = "INTERNAL"
  address      = "10.10.10.42"
  region       = "us-west1"
}

output "manager-ip-one" {
  value = google_compute_address.manager_ip_one.address
}


resource "google_compute_address" "manager_ip_two" {
  name         = "manager-two"
  subnetwork   = google_compute_subnetwork.default.id
  address_type = "INTERNAL"
  address      = "10.10.10.43"
  region       = "us-west1"
}

output "manager-ip-two" {
  value = google_compute_address.manager_ip_two.address
}


resource "google_compute_instance" "manager1" {
  name         = "manager-node-1"
  machine_type = "e2-medium"
  zone         = "us-west1-a"
  tags         = ["ssh"]

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "debian-cloud/debian-10"
    }
  }


  metadata_startup_script = "sudo apt update -y; sudo apt install wget htop -y;"

  network_interface {
    subnetwork = google_compute_subnetwork.default.id
    network_ip = google_compute_address.manager_ip_one.address
    
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo ${google_compute_address.manager_ip_one.address} >> private_ips.txt"
  }
}


resource "google_compute_instance" "manager2" {
  name         = "manager-node-2"
  machine_type = "e2-medium"
  zone         = "us-west1-a"
  tags         = ["ssh"]

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "debian-cloud/debian-10"
    }
  }

  metadata_startup_script = "sudo apt update -y; sudo apt install wget htop -y;"

  network_interface {
    subnetwork = google_compute_subnetwork.default.id
    network_ip = google_compute_address.manager_ip_two.address
    
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo ${google_compute_address.manager_ip_two.address} >> private_ips.txt"
  }
}


resource "google_compute_firewall" "ssh" {
  name = "allow-ssh"
  allow {
    ports    = ["22"]
    protocol = "tcp"
  }
  direction     = "INGRESS"
  network       = google_compute_network.default.id
  priority      = 1000
  source_ranges = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  target_tags   = ["ssh"]
}


resource "google_compute_firewall" "icmp" {
  name = "allow-icmp"
  allow {
    protocol = "icmp"
  }
  direction     = "INGRESS"
  network       = google_compute_network.default.id
  priority      = 1001
  source_ranges = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  target_tags   = ["icmp"]
}
```

Comment: You only have a private IP, so you need a way out like a NAT gateway (or Cloud NAT router in GCP)

Answer (score 1):

I think that in order to access an external internet from a compute engine (leaving aside firewall rules), the compute engine should either have an [external IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking/network-overview#ip-addresses), or a make a connection using a [Cloud NAT](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview#architecture).

> To communicate with the internet, you can use an external IPv4 or external IPv6 address configured on the instance. If the instance doesn't have an external address, Cloud NAT can be used for IPv4 traffic.

In case of an external IP address, you might like to add a few lines into the terraform script (I use a snippet from your code above) configuring an ["access config" section](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance#access_config):

```
  network_interface {
    subnetwork = google_compute_subnetwork.default.id
    network_ip = google_compute_address.manager_ip_one.address
    
    access_config {
      // Ephemeral public IP
    }
  }
```

Or, presumably, you created/reserved an external IP address in your terraform script as well (let's say with a name `manager_ip_ext`):

```
  network_interface {
    subnetwork = google_compute_subnetwork.default.id
    network_ip = google_compute_address.manager_ip_one.address
    
    access_config {
      // Explicit public IP
      nat_ip = google_compute_address.manager_ip_ext.address

    }
  }
```

Another option, as mentioned above, is to organise egress through a Cloud NAT solution. Some details are provided in the documentation - [Set up and manage network address translation with Cloud NAT](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/set-up-manage-network-address-translation) Cloud NAT can be deployed/managed through Terraform as well.